# Flask and Typeahead (bootstrap autocomplete js)

Tags: jquery, flask, bootstrap-typeahead

Trying to get typeahead to work in flask, even simplest code (following [this tutorial](http://blattchat.com/2013/01/09/bootstrap-typeahead/)) doesn't respond with a list of options/highlighted possible items.

I only have a render_template call from the flask main.py, with the corresponding HTML looking like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='jquery.js') }}"></script>
    <link href="{{ url_for('static',filename='bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='typeahead.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div style="margin: 50px 50px">
        <label for="product_search">Product Search: </label>
        <input id="product_search" type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-source='["Deluxe Bicycle", "Super Deluxe Trampoline", "Super Duper Scooter"]'>
    </div>

</body>
```

This code is probably the simplest possible implementation with a local data-source.
Note- I tried changing the scripts initialization order (jquery first, bootstrap.css first, etc..), that didn't help.

Are there any known issues with Flask/Typeahead? Any idea on what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used typeahead myself in a while but the difference I notice between the tutorial and your code is that the tutorial loads the script *after* the typeahead input. As so:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='jquery.js') }}"></script>
    <link href="{{ url_for('static',filename='bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div style="margin: 50px 50px">
        <label for="product_search">Product Search: </label>
        <input id="product_search" type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-source='["Deluxe Bicycle", "Super Deluxe Trampoline", "Super Duper Scooter"]'>
    </div>

    <script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='typeahead.js') }}"></script>

</body>
```

If that does not work either, try triggering the typeahead manually with JS, as shown on [Bootstrap's Site](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#typeahead)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='jquery.js') }}"></script>
    <link href="{{ url_for('static',filename='bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='typeahead.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div style="margin: 50px 50px">
        <label for="product_search">Product Search: </label>
        <input id="product_search" type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-source='["Deluxe Bicycle", "Super Deluxe Trampoline", "Super Duper Scooter"]'>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#product_search').typeahead()
    </script>

</body>
```